# How to insert an item into an empty array at a specific index and other index data value 0?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I want to create array like below ex

Array length must be :- 12 [dynamic count]

Expected Output :- [0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,45,10,0]

I want to create this type of array using js, Need to add any count to specific index

Comment: `var array = [0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,45,10,0]` ... ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code.

```
// Define the length of the array
const length = 12;

// Create an empty array of the specified length
let array = new Array(length).fill(0);

// Define the values and indices to be inserted
const values = [23, 45, 10];
const indices = [4, 9, 10];

// Insert the values at the specified indices
indices.forEach((index, i) => {
  if (index >= 0 && index < length) {
    array[index] = values[i];
  }
});

console.log(array);
```